# Обтекание текстом (Drupal - сборка Drupalife)

Tags: drupal

Доброго всем кодинга.
Вопрос по Drupal 7 (сборка Drupalife) Темизация товара.
Как реализовать обтекание картинки текстом?
Т.е. как из этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сделать нечто такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Насколько помню в сборке используется display suite для отображения нод.
Для решения задачи необходимо переключиться на одноколоночный макет во вкладке "Управление отображением", и сверстать обтекание картинки.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать.

Comment: Что-то получилось? Не забывайте отметить правильный ответ.